# What is this plant with some seeds around its leaf?

Tags: botany, species-identification

I am in India, This plant is growing on floor with very less soil
on it. I took 3 pictures of the same plant, It just rained yesterday. 
I didn't see any insects around this plant. here is it:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Third picture is this: http://i.imgur.com/vxxCJos.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is **Andrographis paniculata** also know as ***Kalmegh*** or ***Kalamegha***

[image]

It has close resemblance to Mexican Tea Plant also.